# Adding a custom font-style in CSS

Tags: html, css, font-face

I downloaded a font from the internet in which it has different styles (bold, italic, etc.). One of the styles is Dashed, so the letters have breaks in them. Is there a way to keep have it under the same family name in a css, just a customized font style. Like if you were in a cms, you can select the option of dashed just like bold.

```
@font-face{
font-family: 'custom-font';
src: url('../font.ttf')format("truetype);
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}

@font-face{
font-family: 'custom-font';
src: url('../font-dash.ttf')format("truetype);
font-weight: normal;
font-style: ???;
}
```

Comment: That's an entirely different font/typeface...not a font-style at all....so NO

Comment: There is no style for that, so you could abuse 'oblique' for it, but it's better to just define a different face like Paulie_D suggests. After all, you're gonna apply that to some CSS classname anyway, so you can hide this in normal use. NB, you have a quote before `truetype`, but not after, I think this is a syntax error.

Comment: I'd say just try and see if it works. But try with all browsers, not just the more popular ones!

Comment: Ok thank you, I will apply them as different font families and whoops was typing too fast @GolezTrol